# IntegrityError at /quiz/api/quiz/ null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to post quiz but getting integrity error.

owner field not getting null instead of current user

serializer.py

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    quiz_id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, default='q'+secrets.token_hex(8))
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['quiz_id', 'owner', 'title', 'description']
```

models.py

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    quiz_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True,null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

Answer (score 0):

Use `HiddenField` instead of `read_only=True`, see: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault but this will make the user not be present in GET response, 
`read_only` fields are ignored in the input, see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only
try:

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    quiz_id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    def save(**kwargs):
        kwargs['owner'] = self.context['request'].user
        kwargs['quiz_id'] = 'q'+secrets.token_hex(8)  # <-- you can have this as a default in model 
        super().save(**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['quiz_id', 'owner', 'title', 'description']
```